# error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'

Tags: android, c++, opencv, c++11, android-ndk

It could be duplicate, but I tried all the solutions that I found on and out StackOverflow.

I'm making a library on C++ with OpenCV and trying to compile it for Android.

I can't use `to_string(int)`but I'm not able. I tried to modify my makefile too many times. My last configuration is this on:

**Android.mk**

> LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
>
> OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
>
> OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
>
> include $(LOCAL_PATH)/jsoncpp/Android.mk
>
> include /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Desktop/AndroidDevelopment/OpenCV-2.4.9-android-
>   sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
>
> OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/opencvscan/OpenCVtry/
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /Users/rafaelruizmunoz/Desktop/RD/OpenCVtry/Libraries/jsoncpp-
>   master/include
>
> LOCAL_PATH := jni
>
> LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
>
> LOCAL_MODULE := libXYZ
>
> LOCAL_MODULE_NAME    := mylibXYZ
>
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES := androidClass.cpp main.cpp utils.cpp
>
> LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -llog -ldl
>
> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS    := -std=c++11 CFLAGS=-g -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings 
>   ../../include/boost
>
> LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libJsoncpp libopencv_java
>
> include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

and this is my **Application.mk**

> APP_STL := gnustl_static
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
>
> APP_ABI := all
>
> APP_MODULES := libXYZ libJsoncpp
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=gnu++0x
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
>
> APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
>
> NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
>
> LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include
>
> APP_USE_CPP0X := true

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your source file including `<string>` before trying to use `std::to_string`...?  If so, you could use `g++ -E ...` to see preprocessor output, and check `to_string` is there... if not check the conditional `#ifdef` in the header and google whatever defines you're missing.   XCode might be defining the extra preprocessor symbols you need...

Comment: yes, it's really working well on XCode. The library works perfectly when I compile it.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do it

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this issue too. to_string is not available in gnu-libstdc++ "out of the box". I searched the sources and found that std::to_string is indeed in the lib (sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/basic_string.h)  but opted out by

```
#if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))
```

After adding -D_GLIBCXX_USE_C99 to the build std::to_string is opted in.

Answer (score 6):

Android NDK 9+ comes with [llvm-libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) which has full support for cpp11 features. To enable it, all you have to do is modify these in Application.mk:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

and

```
APP_STL:=c++_static
```

or

```
APP_STL:=c++_shared
```

Comment: This stdlib is compatible with GCC, not only with clang, is it?

Answer (score 3):

You may try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define TO_STRING to_stringAndroid

template <typename T>
inline std::string to_stringAndroid(const T& value)
{
    std::ostringstream os ;
    os << value ;
    return os.str() ;
}


#else

#define TO_STRING std::to_string

#endif
```

Comment: Better to pass parameter as reference:
`inline std::string to_stringAndroid(const T& value)`